# Problem with freeing a 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, free

I tried to free a 2D array in C using Visual Studio 2005 & 2008:

```
void Free_C(int **Cmat)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<ROW;i++)
       free(Cmat[i]);
    free(Cmat);
}
```

When it get to the second free line it crash with error saying:

```
HEAP CURRUPTION DETECTED:...CRT detected that application wrote to memory after end of heap
```

I allocated the array like this:

```
C=malloc(ROW*sizeof(int*));
for (i=0;i<RC;i++)
    C[i]=malloc(COL*sizeof(int));
```

I also tried that with `calloc`, but it results in the same error.

Comment: How did you allocate that array? Every `free` should correspond to a `malloc` you did earlier.

Comment: Can you show the code you used to allocate the array in the first place?

Comment: This can't really be answered without seeing how you allocated the array.

Comment: Looks okay on first glance, what does `int** Malloc_C(...)` look like?

Comment: the error may indicate that some other part of your program is messing up memory.  run your program with valgrind and make surer there are no warnings printed.

Comment: C=malloc(ROW*sizeof(int*));
    for (i=0;i<RC;i++)
 C[i]=malloc(COL*sizeof(int));

Comment: but i also tried that with calloc, both are not working same error

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to answer this question without first understanding how you allocated the array.  The code you posted appears to be correct assuming the array was itself allocated in a similar manner.  For example (error checking omitted for brevity)

```
int** Malloc_C(int row_size) {
  int** ppArray = malloc(sizeof(int*) * ROW);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
    ppArray[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * row_size);
  }
  return ppArray;
}
```

Comment: @DoronS if that's the case then it's very likely another part of your program is corrupting the memory around the array and hence causing the issue on `free`.  I would start by examining all loops against the outer array and using a program like valgrind to help track down the problem

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you allocated the array, what this could possible mean is the 2D-array was allocated with the first pointer pointing to the entire memory buffer allocated via `malloc()`, and the rest of the pointers in the pointer-array are pointing into the memory buffer.  Therefore, once you've called `free` on the first pointer in the pointer array, you've actually deallocated the entire memory buffer ... calling `free` again on an other pointer in the array will be trying to free memory that has already been deallocated.

For instance, the array could have been allocated using the following technique:

```
int** ptr_array = malloc(sizeof(int*) * NUM_ROWS);
*ptr_array = malloc(sizeof(int) * NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLUMNS);

int* temp = *ptr_array;
for (int i=0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++)
{
    ptr_array[i] = temp;
    temp += NUM_COLUMNS;
}
```